# C# Hashset of char is sorting itself automatically when using add method on it

Tags: c#, generics, collections, hashset

I am trying to solve a string manipulation problem where I need to store characters in a collection that doesn't allow duplicates. So I am using HashSet, however I have noticed that when I am adding characters to it, hashset is getting sorted automatically.

For ex: I had characters 'b' and 'c' in the set already at index 0 and 1 but when I added character 'a' it got added to the index 0 shifting characters 'b' and 'c' to the right at indexes 1 and 2 respectively.

I was under the impression that Hashset are suppose to be not sorted. 
please explain the reason behind this behavior and what else should I use if HashSet is working as it is suppose to be.

Thanks

Comment: They're "not sorted" in that you shouldn't rely on the ordering. It's entirely possible that adding elements in a particular way *may* lead to them being returned in a sorted order, but it's not guaranteed, and the ordering could change between implementation versions.

Answer (score 0):

From *[HashSet<T> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8)*:

> A HashSet collection is not sorted and cannot contain duplicate elements. If order or element duplication is more important than performance for your application, consider using the List class together with the Sort method.

The change in order is due to hashing. Consider using a Dictionary to store the indices along with the characters, Dictionary keys can't be duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

I found this:

[This is what I found on google](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1362/hashset-csharp-with-examples)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally discouraged, and it's not clear how this answers the question anyway.